# Install grails on ubuntu 13.10 amd64

Tags: grails, ubuntu

I am new to use grails and i use amd64's ubuntu 13.10 . When i use [gvm](http://gvmtool.net/) to install grails 2.3.2 successfully then type **grails create-app test**  in my bash, it will appear to be some errors as follow:

```
Loading Grails 2.3.2
Error Error executing script sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1 cannot access 
its superclass sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl 
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

When I just type **grails**,it will appears so errors:

```
Loading Grails 2.3.2
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl
| Error at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
| Error at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
| Error at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
| Error at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
| Error at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
| Error at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:94)
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
| Error at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
| Error at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
...
```

I also use gvm to install groovy, but when i type groovy, it also has errors.
what's wrong about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please execute and allow Permission to the entire Grails folder like this one

Make grails executable have the right permission by just typing

```
`sudo chmod u+x /grailsdirectory/./grails`

`sudo chmod u+x grails-2.3.4 `


`chmod -R 777 /Your/folder/path/`
```

If you just want to make the files read and write assign permission to 766 instead.

## Dude please re-install grails as follow :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grails-ppa

## to add grails 2.3.0          //in my case

sudo apt-get install grails 2.3.0

Then Don't forget to set permission to grails folder and executable also  and Add the nessary environemnt varibles :

```
your JAVA_HOME directory setting
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.xx

#your GRAILS_HOME directory setting
export GRAILS_HOME=~/grails-1.0-RC2

#your PATH setting to append the Grails bin directory
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
```

And , groovy and grails zip package can also be downloaded and extracted to a folder that you want , thens setpermission and then Open or Insatll STS configure grails and groovy thier and ENVIRONEMNTVARIABLES to run grails from Command Line then That is all pretty simple trust me!

[Usefull links :](http://gvmtool.net/)
[Usefull Links:](http://grails.org/download/ubuntu)

Comment: I have done what you have said. I make grails have executing right,and the folders as well, but it has the same error. When i type "grails" not "grails create-app test",my bash shows errors like that:   `Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
`

Comment: Thank you very much!I want to know your ways,please give me your links,thank you!